# Google App Engine JDO and Strong Consistancy

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have been experimenting with GAE (1.7.0) for a couple of weeks now and I am having some issues with STRONG consistancy.

I have been researching the issue, but I am still unclear.

Is some able to definately say that if using JDO within GAE then the consistancy will be EVENTUAL.

The only way to achieve STRONG consistancy is not use JDO and to use the GAE entity classes with Ancestry.

At this stage I dont know if it is my code at fault or just not supported within the environment. In any case I am losing my fragile little mind :-)

My jdoconfig.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

<persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
  <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
    value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
  <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
  <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
  <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
  <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
  <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
  <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="STRONG" />
</persistence-manager-factory>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can be assured of consistency by specifying the datastoreReadConsistency to STRONG in the jdoconfig.xml file.

Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HRD) is now the default data repository for App Engine applications. This model is guaranteed to work for eventual consistency only.

What you have mentioned is correct and also as per the documentation, which states that "To obtain strongly consistent query results, you need to use an ancestor query limiting the results to a single entity group."

See note : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: And indeed Google's JDO/JPA plugin (certainly the current version, not what the user is using) does ancestor queries under some circumstances

Comment: Looks like then I will need to go and investigate it further. I know about objectify, does anyone have any other recommendations?